# Export mongo db into multiple CSV

Tags: mongodb

I've been looking out for a way to export mongo db into csv in multiple files.

- Db contains users from different countries so I want to group users and export CSV for each country separately.

I've tried `mongoExport` but did not work out.

> mongoexport is a utility that produces a JSON or CSV export of data
>   stored in a MongoDB instance.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `--query` parameter in `mongoexport`; see the [`mongoexport --query` documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-query).

For example, my collection is:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0, "country": "US" }
{ "_id": 1, "country": "US" }
{ "_id": 2, "country": "US" }
{ "_id": 3, "country": "AU" }
{ "_id": 4, "country": "AU" }
```

We can then run two `mongoexport` to export each country:

```
$ mongoexport -d test -c test --type=csv --fields="_id,country" --query "{country: 'US'}"
_id,country
0,US
1,US
2,US

$ mongoexport -d test -c test --type=csv --fields="_id,country" --query "{country: 'AU'}"
_id,country
3,AU
4,AU
```

You might want to create a script that first discover the list of countries in the collection, then run `mongoexport` for each of them.